# How should I draw the "Flower of Life" as the background of my dynamic sized webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the Flower of Life, like this one: https://jsfiddle.net/5ak8P

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    compass = new Compass(context, 25, 25, 8),
    flower = [
        { x:  0.00, y:  0 },
        { x: -0.00, y: -2 },
        { x: -1.75, y: -1 },
        { x: -1.75, y: +1 },
        { x: +0.00, y: +2 },
        { x: +1.75, y: +1 },
        { x: +1.75, y: -1 }
    ];

for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) (function (i) {
    var x = flower[i].x,
        y = flower[i].y,
        compass = new Compass(context, 6*x + 25, 6*y + 25, 8);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) (function (i) {
            var x = flower[i].x,
                y = flower[i].y;
            
            setTimeout(function () {
                compass.draw(3*x, 3*y, 6);
            }, 100*i);
        }) (i);
    }, 700*i + 700);
}) (i);

setTimeout(function () { compass.draw(0, 0, 6*3); }, 6*1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://jackvsworld.github.io/static/js/compass.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

However, I want it to be on a canvas that fills the background of my index page. I want it to dynamically fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the following CSS style to the *canvas* element:

```
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

That should do the trick.

NOTE:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

Means the 100% of view-port width and height; if it doesn't suit your page's content try a 100% for both, or change them dynamically with JS according to the current page or view-port ratio (as needed).
For example:
adding this to the JS:

```
window.addEventListener('resize',resizeCanvas,false);

function resizeCanvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    drawFlower();
}
```

Then wrapping the drawing inside a *drawFlower* function:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    compass = new Compass(context, 25, 25, 8),
    flower = [
        { x:  0.00, y:  0 },
        { x: -0.00, y: -2 },
        { x: -1.75, y: -1 },
        { x: -1.75, y: +1 },
        { x: +0.00, y: +2 },
        { x: +1.75, y: +1 },
        { x: +1.75, y: -1 }
    ];
drawFlower();

function drawFlower() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) (function (i) {
        var x = flower[i].x,
            y = flower[i].y,
            compass = new Compass(context, 6*x + 25, 6*y + 25, 8);

        setTimeout(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) (function (i) { 
                var x = flower[i].x,
                    y = flower[i].y;

                setTimeout(function () {
                    compass.draw(3*x, 3*y, 6);
                }, 100*i);
            }) (i);
        }, 700*i + 700);
    }) (i);

    setTimeout(function () { compass.draw(0, 0, 6*3);   }, 6*1000);
}
```

(yes, you still need to change the math for the flower to get a nice looking one...)

Comment: *I want it to be on a canvas that fills the background of my index page*, you need to address this as well.

Comment: The problem there is with the functions drawing the flower: the flower renders well and as perfect circles only when drawn as the author of the fiddle does; you should review the math behind the flower of life and make these formulas dynamic

Comment: From my research I am unsure how to go about doing all this;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_circles_grid

It says to render a new circle the same radius with the center being the exterior intersection of previous circles.

It seems that the function is in fact static for the 7 flower pattern. As oldMammuth said. However, how would I even go about trying to solve this? I have tried http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1367732 but my implementation is sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the exact result I wanted for my background!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
     width = canvas.width = $( document ).width ( ) * 3,
     height = canvas.height = $( document ).height ( ) * 3,
     center_x = cp ( width / 2 ),
     center_y = cp ( height / 2 ),
     radius = 198,
     ordered_pairs = [ ];

window.addEventListener ( 'resize', resizeCanvas, true );

function resizeCanvas ( )
{
    width = canvas.width = $( document ).width ( ) * 3,
   height = canvas.height = $( document ).height ( ) * 3,
    center_x = cp ( width / 2 ),
    center_y = cp ( height / 2 );
   do_fol();
    degree = 0;
}

var red = [ 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet' ];
var orange = [ 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'red' ];
var yellow = [ 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'red', 'orange' ];
var green = [ 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow' ];
var blue = [ 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green' ];
var indigo = [ 'indigo', 'violet', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue' ];
var violet = [ 'violet', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo' ];

var point;

function add_pair ( x, y, color )
{
    point = { 'x': cp ( x ), 'y': cp ( y ), 'color': color };
    if ( ordered_pairs.find ( function ( pair ) { 
        var error_degrees = 1; // if the difference of point x/y is less than the other by this degree of error, it is new.
        // this may increase with more calculations due to floating point percision errors.
        return ( Math.abs ( cp ( pair.x ) - cp ( point.x ) ) < error_degrees && Math.abs ( cp ( pair.y ) - cp ( point.y ) ) < error_degrees );
    } ) == undefined )
    {
        //console.log( point );
        ordered_pairs.push ( point );
        drawArc ( x, y, radius, color );
        //drawArc ( x, y, 0.5, [ 'white' ] );
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //drawArc ( x, y, radius, 'black' );
    }
    return false;
}

function cp ( val )
{
    return round ( val, 5 );
}

function round ( value, decimals )
{
    return Number ( Math.round ( value + 'e' + decimals ) + 'e-' + decimals );
}

function do_fol ( angle = 0 )
{
    ordered_pairs = [ ];
    var x1 = center_x,
         y1 = center_y;
    add_pair ( x1, y1, red );

    angle = cp ( angle * Math.PI * 2 );
    x2 = cp ( Math.cos ( angle ) * radius ) + x1;
    y2 = cp ( Math.sin ( angle ) * radius ) + y1;
    add_pair ( x2, y2, red );

    var pisces = [ ];
         pisces.push ( [ ] );
         pisces.push ( [ ] );
         pisces.push ( [ ] );
         pisces.push ( [ ] );
         pisces.push ( [ ] );

    var points = intersectTwoCircles ( x1, y1, radius, x2, y2, radius );
    for ( var p = 0, s = points.length; p < s; p++ )
    {
        var point = points [ p ];
        add_pair ( point [ 0 ], point [ 1 ], orange );
        var points1 = intersectTwoCircles ( x1, y1, radius, ( point [ 0 ] ), ( point [ 1 ] ), radius );
        for ( var p1 = 0, s1 = points1.length; p1 < s1; p1++ )
        {
            var point1 = points1 [ p1 ];
            add_pair ( point1 [ 0 ], point1 [ 1 ], yellow );
            var points2 = intersectTwoCircles ( x1, y1, radius, ( point1 [ 0 ] ), ( point1 [ 1 ] ), radius );
            for ( var p2 = 0, s2 = points2.length; p2 < s2; p2++ )
            { 
                var point2 = points2 [ p2 ];
                add_pair ( point2 [ 0 ], point2 [ 1 ], green );
                var points3 = intersectTwoCircles ( ( point2 [ 0 ] ), ( point2 [ 1 ] ), radius, ( point1 [ 0 ] ), ( point1 [ 1 ] ), radius );;
                for ( var p3 = 0, s3 = points3.length; p3 < s3; p3++ )
                {
                    var point3 = points3 [ p3 ];
                    if ( add_pair ( point3 [ 0 ], point3 [ 1 ], blue ) )
                    {
                        var points4 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( point3 [ 0 ] ),  ( point3 [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( point1 [ 0 ] ),  ( point1 [ 1 ] ), radius );
                        var points5 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( point3 [ 0 ] ),  ( point3 [ 1 ] ), radius, ( point2 [ 0 ] ),  ( point2 [ 1 ] ), radius );
                        for ( var p4 = 0, s4 = points4.length; p4 < s4; p4++ )
                        {
                            var point4 = points4 [ p4 ];
                            var point5 = points5 [ p4 ];
                            add_pair ( point4 [ 0 ], point4 [ 1 ], indigo );
                            add_pair ( point5 [ 0 ], point5 [ 1 ], indigo );

                            var points6 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( point3 [ 0 ] ),  ( point3 [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( point4 [ 0 ] ),  ( point4 [ 1 ] ), radius );
                            for ( var p5 = 0, s5 = points6.length; p5 < s5; p5++ )
                            {
                                var point6 = points6 [ p5 ];
                                if ( add_pair ( point6 [ 0 ], point6 [ 1 ], violet ) )
                                {
                                    var points8 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( point6 [ 0 ] ),  ( point6 [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( point4 [ 0 ] ),  ( point4 [ 1 ] ), radius );
                                    for ( var p8 = 0, s8 = points8.length; p8 < s8; p8++ )
                                    {
                                        var point8 = points8 [ p8 ];
                                        if ( add_pair ( point8 [ 0 ], point8 [ 1 ], violet ) )
                                        {
                                            pisces [ 2 ].push ( point8 );
                                        }
                                    }
                                    pisces [ 0 ].push ( point6 );
                                    pisces [ 2 ].push ( point6 );
                                }
                            }
                            var points7 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( point3 [ 0 ] ),  ( point3 [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( point5 [ 0 ] ),  ( point5 [ 1 ] ), radius );
                            for ( var p6 = 0, s6 = points7.length; p6 < s6; p6++ )
                            {
                                var point7 = points7 [ p6 ];
                                if ( add_pair ( point7 [ 0 ], point7 [ 1 ], violet ) )
                                {
                                    var points9 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( point7 [ 0 ] ),  ( point7 [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( point5 [ 0 ] ),  ( point5 [ 1 ] ), radius );
                                    for ( var p7 = 0, s7 = points9.length; p7 < s7; p7++ )
                                    {
                                        var point9 = points9 [ p7 ];
                                        if ( add_pair ( point9 [ 0 ], point9 [ 1 ], violet ) )
                                        {
                                            pisces [ 2 ].push ( point9 );
                                        }
                                    }
                                    pisces [ 1 ].push ( point7 );
                                    pisces [ 2 ].push ( point7 );
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        for ( var lr = 0, lrs = ( pisces [ 0 ] ).length; lr < lrs; lr++ )
                        {
                            var left = pisces [ 0 ] [ lr ];
                            var right = pisces [ 1 ] [ lr ];
                            var points10 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( left [ 0 ] ),  ( left [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( right [ 0 ] ),  ( right [ 1 ] ), radius );
                            //console.log (points10);
                            for ( var p9 = 0, s9 = points10.length; p9 < s9; p9++ )
                            {
                                var point10 = points10 [ p9 ];
                                if ( add_pair ( point10 [ 0 ], point10 [ 1 ], red ) )//red ) )
                                {
                                    for ( var lrp = 0, lrps = ( pisces [ 2 ] ).length; lrp < lrps; lrp++ )
                                    {
                                        var lrpisces = pisces [ 2 ] [ lrp ];
                                        var points11 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( point10 [ 0 ] ),  ( point10 [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( lrpisces [ 0 ] ),  ( lrpisces [ 1 ] ), radius );
                                        //console.log (points11);
                                        for ( var p10 = 0, s10 = points11.length; p10 < s10; p10++ )
                                        {
                                            var point11 = points11 [ p10 ];
                                            if ( add_pair ( point11 [ 0 ], point11 [ 1 ], red ) )//red ) )
                                            {
                                                pisces [ 3 ].push ( point11 );
                                                pisces [ 4 ].push ( point11 );
                                            }

                                        }
                                        for ( var lrp1 = 0, lrp1s = ( pisces [ 3 ] ).length; lrp1 < lrp1s; lrp1++ )
                                        {
                                            var lrpisces1 = pisces [ 3 ] [ lrp1 ];
                                            var points12 = intersectTwoCircles (  ( lrpisces [ 0 ] ),  ( lrpisces [ 1 ] ), radius,  ( lrpisces1 [ 0 ] ),  ( lrpisces1 [ 1 ] ), radius );
                                            //console.log (points12);
                                            for ( var p11 = 0, s11 = points12.length; p11 < s11; p11++ )
                                            {
                                                var point12 = points12 [ p11 ];
                                                if ( add_pair ( point12 [ 0 ], point12 [ 1 ], red ) )//red ) )
                                                {
                                                    pisces [ 4 ].push ( point12 );
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    rotate ( );
}

var degree = 0;
function rotate()
{
    $('#canvas').css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    $('#canvas').css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});    
    timer = setTimeout ( function ( ) {
        degree += 1 / 6;
        rotate ( );
    }, 54 );
}

function drawArc ( x, y, r, colors )
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById ( 'canvas' ),
         context = canvas.getContext ( '2d' );
    context.beginPath ( );
    context.arc ( x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI );
    var gradient = context.createLinearGradient ( 0, y - r, 0, y + r );
    for ( var c = 0, cs = colors.length; c < cs; c++ )
    {
        gradient.addColorStop (
            ( ( c == 0 ) ? 0 : ( ( ( c == ( cs - 1 ) ) ? 1 : ( c / ( cs - 1 ) ) ) ) ),
            colors [ c ]
        );
    }
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = gradient;
    context.stroke ( );
}

// based on the math here:
// http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1367732

// x1,y1 is the center of the first circle, with radius r1
// x2,y2 is the center of the second ricle, with radius r2
function intersectTwoCircles(x1,y1,r1, x2,y2,r2) {
    x1 = cp ( x1 ),
    y1 = cp ( y1 ),
    x2 = cp ( x2 ),
    y2 = cp ( y2 );
  var centerdx = x1 - x2;
  var centerdy = y1 - y2;
  var R = Math.sqrt(centerdx * centerdx + centerdy * centerdy);
  if (!(Math.abs(r1 - r2) <= R && R <= r1 + r2)) { // no intersection
    return []; // empty list of results
  }
  // intersection(s) should exist

  var R2 = R*R;
  var R4 = R2*R2;
  var a = (r1*r1 - r2*r2) / (2 * R2);
  var r2r2 = (r1*r1 - r2*r2);
  var c = Math.sqrt(2 * (r1*r1 + r2*r2) / R2 - (r2r2 * r2r2) / R4 - 1);

  var fx = (x1+x2) / 2 + a * (x2 - x1);
  var gx = c * (y2 - y1) / 2;
  var ix1 = fx + gx;
  var ix2 = fx - gx;

  var fy = (y1+y2) / 2 + a * (y2 - y1);
  var gy = c * (x1 - x2) / 2;
  var iy1 = fy + gy;
  var iy2 = fy - gy;

  // note if gy == 0 and gx == 0 then the circles are tangent and there is only one solution
  // but that one solution will just be duplicated as the code is currently written
  return [[ix1, iy1], [ix2, iy2]];
}

function ordered_pair_inArray(haystack, needle){
  var i, j, current;
  for(i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i){
    if(needle.length === haystack[i].length){
      current = haystack[i];
      for(j = 0; j < needle.length && Math.round(needle[j]) == Math.round(current[j]); ++j);
      if(j == needle.length)
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```